# remove specific result in array list java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have `List<Size> sizes = new ArrayList<>();`.
this list is quality for the camera picture.

there is the result of this list of sizes:

```
3264x2448
3264x1836
2880x2160
2560x1440
2048x1152
1920x1080
1440x1080
1280x720
1056x704
1024x768
960x720
800x450
720x480
640x480
352x288
320x240
```

I would like to get the first result of 3xxx, the first result of 2xxx and the first result of 1xxx like :

```
3264x2448
2880x2160
1920x1080
960x720
800x450
720x480
640x480
352x288
320x240
```

what can I do to remove or create a new array with just this result ?

I try somesing like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizes.size(); j++){
    if ( j + 1 < sizes.size() ){
        if( String.valueOf(sizes.get(j).getWidth()).charAt(0) == String.valueOf(sizes.get(j + 1).getWidth()).charAt(0) ){
            sizes.remove(j+1);
        }
    }
    //Log.d(TAG, sizes.get(j).toString() );
}
```

thanks!

Comment: is Size an Enum?

Comment: he can sort by multiplying the values.

Comment: @JayDangar Good idea, but it's more complicated than that unfortunately, because `x*y = y*x`.  So, it would have to sort by the product and also by what the first number is.

Comment: @JayDangar I work with the width of picture sor i want juste the first result for each 1000 pixels

Comment: Yes, you are right, but may be he's getting data as already sorted. :)

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Does the code you've tried work?

Comment: My idea is that override Size object's equals and hashcode methods according to first character and put it in a new list by calling contains method of the list while iterating through sizes list. If list contains method returns false add else dont add. In this way you can group by first character.

Comment: One problem with `String.valueOf(sizes.get(j).getWidth()).charAt(0)` is that "3264" matches "360" since you're only looking at the first character. So if you had 360 straight after 3264, the 360 would be deleted. Another problem is that by creating Strings you're wasting space and CPU time (which may be scarce on an old Android phone). Use width / 1000 (integer division) and compare integers.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException it don't match because I check juste the next result

Comment: Ok but a simple `width/1000` is still more readable (as well as more efficient) than `String.valueOf(sizes.get(j).getWidth()).charAt(0)`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException with cast (int) sizes.get(j).getWidth() / 1000 ?

Comment: No need to cast, assuming `getWidth()` already returns `int`. Integer division always has an integer result.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException perfect thanks !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can go through your list and keep track of the `Nxxx` values you already added to the list and only add the `Size` if its corresponding mask was not already added. Something along these lines:

```
List<Size> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> maskAlreadyInList = new ArrayList<>();
int width;
String widthAsString, mask;
StringBuilder maskBuilder;
for(Size s : sizes) {
    width = s.getWidth();
    widthAsString = String.valueOf(width);
    maskBuilder = new StringBuilder(""+widthAsString.charAt(0));
    for(int i = 1; i < widthAsString.length(); i++) {
        maskBuilder.append("x");
    }
    mask = maskBuilder.toString();

    if (!maskAlreadyInList.contains(mask)) {
        resultList.add(s);
        maskAlreadyInList.add(mask);
    }
}

resultList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs

```
Size{width=3264, height=2448}
Size{width=2880, height=2160}
Size{width=1920, height=1080}
Size{width=960, height=720}
Size{width=800, height=450}
Size{width=720, height=480}
Size{width=640, height=480}
Size{width=352, height=288}
```

NOTE:

Using this definition of `toString` for the Size object

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Size{width="+width+", height="+height +"}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used String in the place of Sizes whose type is not revealed

```
List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Character> firstchar = new ArrayList<>();
      List<String> sizes = new ArrayList<>();

      for(String size:sizes){
          if(!firstchar.contains(size.charAt(0))){
              filtered.add(size);
              firstchar.add(size.charAt(0));
          }
      }
      for(String elem:filtered){
          System.out.println(elem);
      }
```

Comment: I think this will not add `352` because `3264` has already been added and `3` is in the list

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment I implemented the case according to below. You can test it.
My idea is that override Size object's equals and hashcode methods according to first character and put it in a new list by calling contains method of the list while iterating through sizes list. If list contains method returns false add else dont add. In this way you can group by first character

```
 public class Size {
        private String dimension;

        public Size(String dimension) {
            this.dimension = dimension;
        }

        public String getDimension() {
            return dimension;
        }

        public void setDimension(String dimension) {
            this.dimension = dimension;
        }

        public String getDimensionFirstPart() {
            return this.dimension.split("x")[0];
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((dimension == null) ? 0 : dimension.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Size other = (Size) obj;
            if (dimension == null) {
                if (other.dimension != null)
                    return false;
            } 
            else if (getDimensionFirstPart().length() == other.getDimensionFirstPart().length() && 
                    getDimensionFirstPart().charAt(0) == other.getDimensionFirstPart().charAt(0))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return dimension;
        }
    }
```

Test class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Size size1 = new Size("3264x2448");
        Size size2 = new Size("3264x1836");
        Size size3 = new Size("2880x2160");
        Size size4 = new Size("2560x1440");
        Size size5 = new Size("2048x1152");
        Size size6 = new Size("1920x1080");
        Size size7 = new Size("1440x1080");
        Size size8 = new Size("1280x720");
        Size size9 = new Size("320x240");
        Size size10 = new Size("352x288");
        Size size11 = new Size("960x720");
        Size size12 = new Size("800x450");

        List<Size> sizes = new ArrayList<Size>();
        sizes.add(size1);sizes.add(size2);sizes.add(size3);sizes.add(size4);sizes.add(size5);sizes.add(size6);sizes.add(size7);sizes.add(size8);
        sizes.add(size9);sizes.add(size10);sizes.add(size11);sizes.add(size12);
        List<Size> newSizes = new ArrayList<Size>();
        for(Size size: sizes) {
            if(!newSizes.contains(size)) {
                newSizes.add(size);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newSizes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of a limit, a muliplier of 1000, and add only one element for each change in limit.

```
List<Size> selected = new ArrayList<>();
int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for (Size size : sizes) {
  if (limit == 0) { break; }
  int width = size.getWidth();
  if (width < limit && width >= 1000) {
    selected.add(size);
    limit = (width / 1000) * 1000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) (Java 8 and above) to filter the items and create a new list with desired items

Assuming your `Size` object is as

```
public class Size {
    private String size;

    Size(String s) {
        this.size = s;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

you can write the logic as below

```
String threeSeries = "3[\\d]{3}x[\\d]{4}";
String twoSeries = "2[\\d]{3}x[\\d]{4}";
String oneSeries = "1[\\d]{3}x[\\d]{3,4}";

List<Size> result = new ArrayList<>();

result.add(sizes.stream().filter((s) -> s.getSize().matches(threeSeries)).findFirst().get());
result.add(sizes.stream().filter((s) -> s.getSize().matches(twoSeries)).findFirst().get());
result.add(sizes.stream().filter((s) -> s.getSize().matches(oneSeries)).findFirst().get());

result.addAll(sizes.stream().filter(
        (s) -> !s.getSize().matches(threeSeries) && !s.getSize().matches(twoSeries) && !s.getSize().matches(oneSeries))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

result.forEach((s) -> System.out.println(s.getSize()));
```